# SQL Join (3 tables)

Tags: sql, join

i am rly struggling with an sql statement and think i need some advice:

I have 4 tables:

**staff**:
staff_Id , staff_firstname, staff_lastname

**user**:
ssh_user_id, ssh_user_server_id, ssh_user_name

**server**:
server_id, server_name

**user_staff**
staff_id, ssh_user_id

I have a **server_id** and i need all **staff_names**, who are not connected to each of the server's user.

For example i have "max" (staff) who is conntected to "root"(user) in the merge-table(staff_user) from "testserver"(server) , but he is not connected to "testuser"(user) from the same server. I want him to be in the result, same with "melanie", who isnt conntected to "root" AND "testuser".

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cte.staff_id 
FROM (
       SELECT st.staff_id, ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY st.staff_id ORDER BY s.server_id) AS cnt
       FROM Staff st
       INNER JOIN user_staff u_s ON u_s.staff_id = st.staff_id
       INNER JOIN user u ON u.ssh_user_id = u_s.ssh_user_id
       INNER JOIN server s ON s.server_id = u.ssh_user_server_id
     ) cte
WHERE cte.cnt < ( 
                  SELECT COUNT(s2.server_id)
                  FROM server s2
                )
```